# How to get the filtered array from Vuetify v-data-table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

This is how is my data table is

```
<v-data-table
 :search="search"
 :headers="tableHeaders"
 :items="tableItems"
 hide-default-footer
 ></v-data-table>
```

Is there any way to get the *filtered items* from data table after search filter is applied. I am passing array in `:items` which is being filtered by `:search`.

Comment: Why don't you create a computed variable out of `tableItems` that filters the items based on your search filter and pass the new variable to the `items` prop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add a handler to `@current-items` event like :

```
@current-items="getFiltered"
```

and add it to your methods as follows:

```
methods:{
  getFiltered(e){
   console.log(e) //output the filtered items
 }
}
```

check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/mddmNoK?editors=1011)

Comment: So I tried this and realized that this does not work when the results returned are more than 1 page. It only returns the result on the current page. Example pen: [Test Pen](https://codepen.io/prasadchinwal5/pen/eYmbvYb). Please enter 500 in the Less than filter under Calories column

Comment: This worked for me: search(val) {
      if (val !== "" && val !== null) {
        return (this.itemsPerPage = -1);
      } else {
        return (this.itemsPerPage = 10);
      }
    },